Fractional Fourier Transform rotation of a chirp
I'm trying to wrap my head around something I read in a paper:

"The Wigner distribution of a linear chirp signal x(t) illustrates how the FrFT (Fractional Fourier Transform) may be used to rotate a linear chirp signal into a tone, which compresses it into fewer samples. If we rotate to the axis t_a, 0 < a < 2, and compute the energy in the FrFT, the chirp projects onto the axis as a strong energy tone. We can detect it by finding the peak of the energy, i.e., taking the magnitude squared of the FrFT. The best rotational axis t_a may be found by searching over all values of 'a', using a reasonable search step size, and finding the peak at each rotational value. The value of 'a' that gives the strongest peak is selected, which we denote a_opt. To retain the chirp simply requires retaining one sample, i.e., the peak value of the rotated signal, and removing (i.e., notching) the rest."

I think I understand how the linear chirp rotates to a tone by some order of the FrFT, but what do they mean by reducing it to one sample? What is the time-domain modulation that gets used by the transmitter? They apply a similar method to a hyperbolic chirp, with more samples retained.

Link to the paper? This sounds like it's doing a dechirp operation.

what'sa "FrFT"?

Paywalled version is here:
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9401866/
FrFT is Fractional Fourier Transform
